# Error: "Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist" when adding MySQL-Data Source to Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to add a MySQL-Data Source to my Visual Studio project. 
I am using MySQL Server 8.0.12 and also the 8.0.12 Connector/MySql.data. 
 In the Data Source Configuration Wizard an error pops up when choosing the database objects: 
"An error occurred while retrieving the information from the database: Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist"

I already tried executing the 'mysql_upgrade.exe' as suggested in other solutions but this specific table wasnt affected. Then i found this blogpost:

[No more mysql.proc in MySQL 8.0](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/)

Is there any work-around for this  except down-grading the MySQL Server version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of downgranding to the earlier MySQL version, you could update to MariaDB which still has the mysql.proc.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just put 
`CheckParameters=False;` in your .NET connection string i.e. in your config file.

No need to downgrade the MySQL server,
I guess it is bug from MySQL .NET connector.

Comment: This causes ```System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: checkparameters
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ValidateKeyword(String keyword)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)```