# Table mysql.proc does not exist (issue in Visual Studio 2017)?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to populate a `DataGrid` in Visual Studio 2017 WinForms application from a `MySQL Database`. However VS Studio throws an error stating that table `mysql.proc` does not exist (as shown in the screenshot). I would like to ask how can I fix this error provided that I installed the recommended connector and add-on for Visual Studio 2017 stated in the official MySQL Website?

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Z79.png)

Comment: Hard to say how to fix something without seeing what code you've written. Also, are you sure "mysql.proc" is a table name and not something else in the db? Like a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

The mysql.proc table (which indeed is a table not a stored procedure) was removed in MySQL 8.0. You can find an earlier mention of the issue here: [Error: "Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist" when adding MySQL-Data Source to Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712260/error-table-mysql-proc-doesnt-exist-when-adding-mysql-data-source-to-visua) The solution (after looking at the blog post mentioned there) was "switch to a different product", and downgrading to MySQL 5.7 would work too. You might want to look at "MySQL Upgrade Strategies" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/upgrading-strategies.html which mentions the backup of MySQL-5.7's proc, but I'm afraid that won't necessarily change what Visual Studio looks for.