# Procedure call not working via ProxySql, error MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, database-replication, mysql-8.0, proxysql

I have two RDS instances for mysql, 1 master node and 1 replication slave node. I have setup a ProxySql EC2 instance listening on 6033 port which routes all the write requests to master node and all the read requests to slave node.

In my .NET code if I execute simple **inline query** like "select * from tableX;" then it executes via ProxySql EC2 instance but when I put this statement in a procedure and call that procedure via c# code it throws an error:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist

I am using MySql.Data 8.0.13 nuget package for database interaction. Mysql version is 8.0.13 on AWS RDS.

In .NET application the connection string is:

> server=xxx.amazonaws.com;Port=6033;user=xxx;database=abc;password=xxxx;charset=utf8mb4;

Also, if I connect through SqlYog I am able to execute the procedure without any errors, but with .NET it is not working.

Comment: We have tried doing this on ProxySql 1.4.14 and 2.0.1. In both the cases result was the same...

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712260/error-table-mysql-proc-doesnt-exist-when-adding-mysql-data-source-to-visua

Comment: Also this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93814. Are you sure proxysql is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add **CheckParameters=false** in your connection string:

```
server=xxx.amazonaws.com;Port=6033;user=xxx;database=abc;password=xxxx;charset=utf8mb4;CheckParameters=false;
```